# Possible screen share in the background by Bitdefender

Tags: spyware, screen-capture

Recently I was chatting with Bitdefender support through their support center and one weird thing I noticed was that the support person would be answering my questions right after I sent them without even taking the time to read or think about them and sometimes they would answer it before I even sent the question. So this raises my suspicion that they would somehow know what I'm typing through some sort of screen share. When I monitor my network usage there are constant connections by Bitdefender agents in the background. They frequently connect to the network. If it's some update check shouldn't it be done like every hour or so instead of all the time? I fear there is some sort of periodic screenshot share at play here. So can anyone give me any sort of assurance that nothing is being shared and that I am safe using their products?

Comment: It is not fully clear here what you are doing: You cannot expect everybody to already know the interaction with Bitdefender support works yet you don't explain it in sufficient detail. But if you write anything in a chat box in __their__ site they can well read what you are typing before you hit an explicit submit button - without needing any kind of screen sharing for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well, they were using the [LiveChat Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livechat_Software) plugin instead of implementing their own chat box, so I doubt that they would have such privileged access and since when they were typing I could only see 3 dots, I would assume that they would see the same on their side when I was typing.

Comment: Still the amount of background connections doesn't make sense IMHO.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what's going on based on this description. It is not clear what *"the amount of ..."* actually means in detail, i.e. how many connections, how many data transferred, traffic pattern, context and content of data ... . Just because something does not make sense for somebody does not mean that it is malicious. It might simply be a lack of information and understanding instead.

Comment: Just because you see 3 dots doesn't mean they do. And perhaps your questions were not  as unique to you as you think and they anticipated your questions

Comment: So instead of telling me what to do to "clarify" things for you and what pattern to look for in the network capture, you rant about not having enough information. That's very helpful. Is that how pen-testers do their job?